# PHP : add a delete button in last column to delete a table row

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have a table displayed in HTML. I want to add a button `delete` in the last column to remove the considered line of the table. Thus, I create a form in my last column, with a hidden value, which is `id` (= primary key of my table entry), to pass id, through a POST method, in another page to launch an DELETE SQL query. The below code is not working :

```
<form action="delete_facture.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="id2" value="<?php $donnees['id'] ?>"/>
            <input type="submit" value="delete"/>
</form>
```

Than the delete_facture.php is the following :

```
<?php
// Connexion à la base de données
try
{
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'root', '');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
$req = $bdd->prepare('DELETE FROM factures WHERE id= :id2');
$req->execute(array(
                    ':id2'=>$_POST['id2']
                    ));
header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

What's wrong in my code ? Thank you.

Comment: what happens when you click "delete" button?

Comment: @gaskar Nothing happens. I stay on my table page...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put `echo`, then only it will assign the value in the textbox. Otherwise you will get empty value. Try this,

```
<input type="hidden" name="id2" value="<?php echo $donnees['id'] ?>"/>
```

Comment: Exactly. A good approach to debug a form post is to check what data is actually posted!